# Annotation.js & PDF.js extracting Checkbox/Radio Values from pdf files

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

I have search far and wide and all node libraries have failed me!

I am trying to extract/parse a uploaded PDF (server side) checkboxes/radio selected values. I am stuck and do not know where I can extract this data using PDF.js in node. Any ideas? Is annotation.js my direction? If so, how to I extract that data without display the pdf.

Comment: Hi artem, it is best to visit their github page and open a new issue with your question. They can certainly guide you on that.